# Display Detail firebase data from listview onitemclick Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem I am facing is that I cannot display the detail of the `ListView` on which I clicked, any suggestion to display the detail of the Firebase data, I'm done for itemOnClick and change to another activity, but the problem is that it shows only the text of `ListView` and not the detail, thank you

**LISTVIEW JAVA CLASS**

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        final String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Sample.class).toString();
        arrayList.add(0,value);
        listcase.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Report.class);
                //String sample = String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i));//arrayAdapter.getItem(i);
                intent.putExtra("sample", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i)));
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_entering, R.anim.slide_right_exiting);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**CONSTRUCTOR**

```
public Sample() {
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getSymthom() {
    return symthom;
}

public void setSymthom(String symthom) {
    this.symthom = symthom;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public String getDateDiag() {
    return DateDiag;
}

public void setDateDiag(String dateDiag) {
    DateDiag = dateDiag;
}

public String toString (){
    return "Sample Name : " + Name + "\n"+ "Status : ";
}
```

**DETAIL JAVA CLASS**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("sample"))
{
    textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("sample"));
}
```

I have no idea how to display detail of my Firebase object to another activity, thank you for helping me

Comment: add some description as to what is your code that has been posted is doing and in which part of your code you are facing issues

Comment: Please try to post your code in a way, that it is readable. furhtermore, where is your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please Help me, to fix the problem and thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayList` contains an only `String`, not a detail object.

```
final String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Sample.class).toString();
```

So when you get by index it returns item value. If you share the value of   **value** JSON structure it would be good to understand better.

Comment: can you give the structure itself, im beginner so i confuse to display the detail of my constructor data. thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

```
  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot){
                    Log.d("data", "onDataChange: "+ dataSnapshot);
                    Sample Sample = snapshot.getValue(Sample.class);
                    sampleList.add(Sample);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: hope this will help you

Comment: okey thanks, im done for dislaying at listview in that code i shoe the name, but i want to view the detail like address etc in the textview based on listview itemonclik thank you